# Airline Route Map

Tags: html, flash

I was wondering, how can I create a route map similar to this one?

http://www.flightmapping.com/maps/uk-ireland

I need something similar for my virtual airline, and the trouble is that I'm clueless on how to do it on Flash. Is there any other way I could produce such a map, maybe through CSS or something, or is there any useful tutorial about on how I could produce something like this on Flash?

Thank you,
HighFlyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [amMap](http://ammap.com/examples/flight_routes) for this type of thing. Doesn't require you to know Flash and utilizes data files which you can then update dynamically if you want. They have a free version you can use that just has an attribution on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [interactive flight routing map](http://www.imapbuilder.com/interactive_map_resources/airline_route_map_flight_airways.php) which is also created in flash using the imap mapping software. They do have a free trial version for you to download from their website.